# matplotlib logarithmic y axis format

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I have an issue with the output format of a semilogy plot in python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3, 10, 1)
y = x**2

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(8, 80)
ax.set_yticks([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80])
ax.set_yticklabels(['10', '20', '30', '50', '60', '70', '80'])
plt.show()
```

my output is this[image]

it seems the log scale is creating new tick labels which remain when I create the ones I want. I tried to solve it by adding

```
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

right before the ticks definition, but unfortunately it didn't work.
Everything is fine in linear scale.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when I changed the y_lim it seems to work well with certain values. Try this ax.set_ylim(7 , 80). Not sure why it is so.

Comment: Actually the previous question that ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out by flagging as duplicate (which I completely missed)  solves the problem